# Why are certain 64 bit applications installed by default on the Program Files (x86) folder

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, 32-bit

I read that, by convention, the Program Files folder is for 64 bit applications and the Program Files (x86) folder is for 32 bit folders. I understand that it doesn't really matter which folder the program is installed in, but usually 64 bit applications  are installed in the first and 32 bit applications in the latter.

Why are certain 64 bit applications installed by default on the Program Files (x86) folder?

Examples include Overwatch, Steam, Nvidia, Overworlf, Mendeley, Arduino, Battle.net.

Comment: Are aware that Battle.net, Steam, Nvidia (Geforce Experience), are not actually 64-bit applications?

Answer (score 2):

Programs that are combined 32-bit and 64-bit are installed in Program Files (x86).

64-bit only applications are stored in Program Files.

In addition to your list, VMware Workstation, and others are a single version, combining 32-bit apps and 64-bit apps.

I now see more applications coming in 64-bit versions separately from 32-bit versions and all the 64-bit versions go in Program Files.

There is not yet a cohesive standard for Windows and it is very much up to the application Vendor where they put their programs.

What you see is entirely normal.